# Relative velocity in SR as tangent of both Euclidean and hyperbolic angle?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry

When drawing a Minkowski diagram, one chooses a frame of reference whose axes are painted perpendicular to each other. Given a second frame that is moving in the positive X axis of the first at velocity $v$, its axes will be painted tilted by an angle $θ$, which is chosen so that $tan(θ) = v/c$. So we are talking here about an Euclidean angle and the Eulidean tangent.

However, it is also said that a Lorentz boost is a hyperbolic rotation (the hyperbolic angle is called rapidity) and that that the hyperbolic tangent of this hyperbolic angle is equal to $v/c$.

For example, I usually choose $v = 0.5c$, which is the Euclidean tangent of an angle of approx. 26.5651 degrees. In turn, $arctanh(0.5)$ gives a hyperbolic angle of $0.54930614$.

My question is if then a Minkowski diagram can be drawn based, alternatively, on either method, and if so, whether someone could possibly provide a drawing where they converge.

Comment: It is very nice to play with Minkowski diagrams. If you have drawn enough of them, you can show to yourself that the hyperbolic angles are a nice parametrisation but will not appear on any diagram, whereas the Euclidean angles will appear on some Minkowski diagram but have no physical existence/interpretation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent But then the hyperbolic angle is of no assistance in drawing the diagram?

Comment: That is correct. But it was never promoted as being able to help with that. What it helps with is that it is the natural additive parameter for composing Lorentz boosts. i.e. you can add simply two rapidities and it will correspond to the relativistic velocity addition formula.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true for a given slope (velocity) that
$(v/c)=\tanh\theta =\tan\phi$,
under a Lorentz boost of the diagram
only $\theta$ remains unchanged as the rapidity between the boosted rays
(the original t-axis boosted and the original 4-velocity boosted).

It's not clear to me what you mean by
"a drawing where they converge."

Comment: The question boils down to whether, knowing the hyperbolic angle, you can somehow calculate where to place the cT's axis with regard to cT (or X' wrt X). If this could be done, then the outcome would be the same as if you had used the Euclidean angle. In this sense, the two methods would converge on the same drawing. I gather from natuarallyInconsistent's comment that the answer may be no, that the hyperbolic angle is good for parametrization but of no assistance in drawing (?).

Comment: @Sierra The radian-angle in Euclidean geometry and rapidity in Minkowski geometry is proportional to the area of the sector in the unit-"circle" in the geometry. Under a boost, the area of the sector in the unit-hyperbola is unchanged. So, that could provide assistance in drawing. I don't understand the issue. For example, I use Desmos to do relativity calculations using velocities and rapidities... then I may use ordinary geometry to plot it on the screen or on paper.

Comment: I think that I understand the thing now. Based on the value of $v/c$, you can deduce both Euclidean and hyperbolic angle and, thus, you can plot points of the cT' axis as either (sinh,cosh) or (sin,cos). So both methods are of assistance in drawing and indeed do converge on drawing the same line for cT'. A different thing is that if you want to add another frame, hyperbolic angles are additive, while Euclidean ones are not.